# Is it possible that OpenMPI corrupts malloc() metadata? If yes, how and why?

Tags: c++, mpi, openmpi

I have an OpenMPI program creating an Inter-communicator with `MPI_Spawn()`.

One of the processes in the second group dies most of the time with the following error output:

```
corrupted double-linked list
[local-pc:16468] *** Process received signal ***
[local-pc:16468] Signal: Aborted (6)
[local-pc:16468] Signal code:  (-6)
[local-pc:16468] [ 0] /lib64/libc.so.6(+0x3ea70)[0x7f0d37d2ea70]
[local-pc:16468] [ 1] /lib64/libc.so.6(+0x8ec4c)[0x7f0d37d7ec4c]
[local-pc:16468] [ 2] /lib64/libc.so.6(raise+0x16)[0x7f0d37d2e9c6]
[local-pc:16468] [ 3] /lib64/libc.so.6(abort+0xcf)[0x7f0d37d187f4]
[local-pc:16468] [ 4] /lib64/libc.so.6(+0x82d9e)[0x7f0d37d72d9e]
[local-pc:16468] [ 5] /lib64/libc.so.6(+0x9895c)[0x7f0d37d8895c]
[local-pc:16468] [ 6] /lib64/libc.so.6(+0x99414)[0x7f0d37d89414]
[local-pc:16468] [ 7] /lib64/libc.so.6(+0x9c03d)[0x7f0d37d8c03d]
[local-pc:16468] [ 8] /lib64/libc.so.6(__libc_calloc+0xd9)[0x7f0d37d8d969]
[local-pc:16468] [ 9] /usr/lib64/openmpi/lib/openmpi/mca_coll_libnbc.so(+0x78d4)[0x7f0d354418d4]
[local-pc:16468] [10] /usr/lib64/openmpi/lib/openmpi/mca_coll_libnbc.so(+0xff49)[0x7f0d35449f49]
[local-pc:16468] [11] /usr/lib64/openmpi/lib/openmpi/mca_coll_libnbc.so(ompi_coll_libnbc_ibarrier_inter+0x13)[0x7f0d3544a393]
[local-pc:16468] [12] /usr/lib64/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so.40(MPI_Ibarrier+0x69)[0x7f0d382a4239]
[local-pc:16468] [13] /home/user/project/worker0[0x408edc]
[local-pc:16468] [14] /lib64/libc.so.6(+0x29550)[0x7f0d37d19550]
[local-pc:16468] [15] /lib64/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0x89)[0x7f0d37d19609]
[local-pc:16468] [16] /home/user/project/worker0[0x406e25]
[local-pc:16468] *** End of error message ***
```

The MPI-function is not always the same, so `MPI_Ibarrier` is misleading in this example.

Sadly, my code base is several thousand lines long and I was not able to construct a minimum (not) working example.

I have already found out, that `corrupted double-linked list` means that `malloc()` screwed up but I do not see how and why.

So how does this happen and how do I fix it?

Comment: try `mpirun ... valgrind ...` and look for something suspicious.

Comment: When you suspect a MPI library (instead of your own code), a simple test is to try an other implementation from a different vendor. In your case, you can try MPICH and see how it goes.